# Can we use PDFRenderer in a service?

Tags: android, pdf

I'm writing a `PrinterService` to control a proprietary printer and I try to use `PDFRenderer` to convert the PDF file sent by the `PrinterManager` to a bitmap to be sent to the printer.

I started from this [example](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-PdfRendererBasic) to use PDFRenderer.

I'm sure about the PDF file I receive but `mCurrentPage.render(bitmap, null, null, PdfRenderer.Page.RENDER_MODE_FOR_PRINT);` desesperately fill up an empty bitmap.

So I was wondering if `PDFRenderer` could need some context not available in a service.

Comment: Bear in mind that `PdfRenderer` cannot render arbitrary PDFs. It is designed to render PDFs created using Android's built-in PDF options (e.g., drawing to a PDF-backed `Canvas`). Most likely, you need to come up with some other PDF rendering option. That being said, I would expect `PdfRenderer` to work in a service. Try your test PDF with an app that uses `PdfRenderer` in an activity, such as [this one](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.9/PDF/PdfRenderer). If the PDF renders, then the service is the problem. If the PDF shows up blank, then `PdfRenderer` is the problem.

Comment: @CommonsWare, Do you suggest that Android PrinterManager not mandatory create valid PDF files? Anyway I tried in the service, to read a real PDF file and the result is the same, `mCurrentPage.render` gives me an empty bitmap.

Comment: "Do you suggest that Android PrinterManager not mandatory create valid PDF files?" -- no, I am saying that `PdfRenderer` is for print preview of Android SDK-generated PDF files. You are not using it for that purpose, and so it may or may not work for your use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Preamble

You say:

> "I tried in the service, to read a real [PDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Document_Format) file and the result is the
>   same"

So your problem is reading the `Android` valid [PDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Document_Format) ? So share *that* code.
You have a **working example**, and by  *transferring* the example to a [Service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) have ***broken*** it.

## Let's go on

Your [example](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-PdfRendererBasic) contains a sample (`Android` valid `PDF`) [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-PdfRendererBasic/blob/master/Application/src/main/assets/sample.pdf).

## Possibilities

The code *below* **WILL** work in a `Service` (your worries about `context` in the case of the active code I'm showing is *unwarranted*, were not using `context`). I'm guessing using my *spider-senses* you have a simple bug in transferring the example code into a service (maybe in [PDFRenderer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/pdf/PdfRenderer.html) {added in API level 21}. ? your not crashing so probably no `NULL's` ?). You need to **debug** your code, we cannot help you unless you share it.

## breakdown

Let's break it down, this is the basic way to use [PDFRenderer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/pdf/PdfRenderer.html).

```
 // create a new renderer
 //PdfRenderer renderer = new PdfRenderer(getSeekableFileDescriptor());

PdfRenderer.Page mCurrentPage = renderer.openPage(0);
int h =  mCurrentPage.getHeight();
Log.e("debug PDF render","height:"+h);
int w =  mCurrentPage.getWidth();
Log.e("debug PDF render","width:"+w);
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, w, h);
mCurrentPage.render(bitmap, rect, null, PdfRenderer.Page.RENDER_MODE_FOR_PRINT);
mCurrentPage.close();
```

## results

Once we get a *populated* `bitmap` were in *business* right ?

Comment: everything is ok with sample.pdf. I think I have something strange with the pdf generated by Android's PrinterManager.